# how to set up raylib with c++ binding in sublime text 3 and visual studio 2019 community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sublimetext3, game-development, raylib

I tried to set up raylib 3.0 and raygui 2.6 on Windows 10 with sublime text 3 and vs 2019. I followed the guide on github, but it was met for C. I think I probably mess up the C++ binding part.

I wonder if anyone could provide a step by step tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think you messed it up? What have you tried? What works or doesn't work? What build system are you using? If you installed VS community already, why not work in that instead of sublime text?

Comment: VS 2019 needs setup too. I can't get it work either. As for vs 2019, I setup includes, linking and libraries then click build. vs 2019 gives errors sayinga few xxx.h not found, but they are all added to include.

Comment: Then you did not set it up correctly. Did you follow the [setup guide](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Create-Visual-Studio-Project)? A common gotcha is specifying configuration for the wrong build type or platform, or accidentally specifying the build path a directory too high or low. Show us your build settings and the layout of your code and raylib's.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I can confirm that the issue is from cpp wrapper.  Once I removed the cpp wrapper from my include path (VC++ Directories->Include Directories),  replaced the cpp example with the c one, I was able to get raylib window to initialize.

Comment: https://github.com/robloach/raylib-cpp this one? That's CMake-based, you should be able to just generate a project from that OR include it in your own CMake build. I strongly suggest learning CMake anyway, as that gives you platform and IDE portability.

Comment: Yes. That the one I am trying to get it works.

Comment: I got error like: raylib-cpp-3.0.0\include\Vector2.hpp(80,11): error C3861: 'Vector2Multiply': identifier not found

Comment: See the CMake build instructions, as well as the git submodule instructions (which probably pulls in the C raylib library)

Comment: Thank you for you help.